# Printing Columns with a correlation greater than 80%

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a size of `235607 records`, and `94 attributes`. I am very new `python` I was able to create a correlation matrix between all of the attributes but it is a lot to look through individually. I tried writing a for loop to print a list of the columns with a correlation greater than 80% but I keep getting the error "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'c1'"

This is the code I used to create the correlation between the attributes as well as the sample for loop. Thank you in advance for your help :-

```
corr = data.corr() # data is the pandas dataframe
c1 = corr.abs().unstack()
c1.sort_values(ascending = False)
drop = [cols for cols in upper.c1 if any (upper[c1] > 0.80)]
drop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use the `numpy.where` like this:

```
corr.loc[np.where(corr>0.8, 1, 0)==1].columns
```

the output would be array with the names of the columns, which are having values greater then `0.8`.

**EDIT:** I hope this will work. I edited the code above little.

Comment: Doing that does work however, it does not give me the names of the columns which is what I am having trouble displaying since it  is pretty tedious to look at each column individually. Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 2):

Sort in place, if you need to use the same variable `c1` and then just grab the variables-names pair, using a comprehensive list using the indexes

```
c1.sort_values(ascending=True, inplace=True)
columns_above_80 = [(col1, col2) for col1, col2 in c1.index if c1[col1,col2] > 0.8 and col1 != col2]
```

**Edit**: Added `col1 != col2` in the comprehensive list so you don't grab the auto-correlation